# Jquery Modal UI dialog in infinite loop - only in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

**Problem:**

I'm required to call custom function `ValidateNumericInputBox`, which will return focus to a text field which will cause an infinite loop.

I originally had buttons that would perform the lookup, but after going over the page with our end users it was decide to have lookups/validations performed on exit of the text field. So I need to find a way to kill this infinite loop that is created from conflicting code. The weird part is that this doesn't occur in Chrome or Firefox, only IE.

**Original Problem:**

IE freezes (infinite loop) when I have a jquery modal dialog box open for an error. In the IE developer tools I can see it looping. This does not occur in Firefox and Chrome.

**Code:**

```
$(DivID).dialog({ 
  width:375, 
  height:550, 
  modal:true, 
  closeOnEscape:true,  
  buttons: [ { text: "Ok", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } } ] 
});
```

From research on SO I read that having this line would help:

`close: function(event,ui){},`

Issue still occurs when added. This is source:

[JQuery dialog freezing on close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082024/jquery-dialog-freezing-on-close?rq=1)

**Display Dialog Box Code**

```
function DialogBox(Params){ 
 ...
 variables
 ...

 if(arrParams[3])
  errMsg = arrParams[3]; //custom error message

 // CLOSE DIALOG BOX
 if (DivStatus == 'Close'){ 
  $(DivID).hide();
  $(DivID).dialog('close');
 }
 else if(DivStatus === 'Open'){
   ....
   logic for determining err msg
   ....                          

   $(DivID).dialog({ width:375, height:550, modal:false, closeOnEscape:true, focus:    function( event, ui ) {}, buttons: [ { text: "Ok", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } } ] });

}
else{   //  General error message - uncaught error
 if (DivID == '#Div_ErrorMessage')
   {    $(DivID).dialog({ width:375, height:150, modal:true, closeOnEscape:true, close: function(event,ui){},buttons: [ { text: "Ok", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } } ] });    }
 }
}
```

**HTML DIV For Dialog Box**

```
<div id="Div_Wrapper" style="background:#EBEBEB;">
            <div id='Div_LoadingOverlay' class="Div_LoadingOverlay_Relative noPrint"><div class='Div_LoadingOverlay'><br><br><img src='/common/images/misc/loader_01.gif' align='absmiddle' /><br>Loading...</div></div>
            <div id='Div_ErrorMessage' style='display:none;' title='Error Message'>There seems to be something wrong with the form...</div>
```

**Research:**

[JQuery dialog freezing on close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082024/jquery-dialog-freezing-on-close?rq=1)

[jquery Ui-dialog and ie8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251176/jquery-ui-dialog-and-ie8)

A lot of issues that I researched are dated <= 2010, and deal with browsers that I don't support. Also are not completely relevant.

**Browsers tested**

IE 9,10  - does not work

Firefox 18.0.1 - works

Chrome Version 34.0.1847.137 m - works

**More test cases:**

1) Removed `$( this ).dialog( "close" );` in the click function. - Does not work.

2) Brought things back to the basics and copied and pasted the code straight from jquery's website

```
$( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
      height: 140,
      modal: true
    });
```

Changing of course `#dialog-modal` to be `DivId`. - This does not work.

**EDIT 0**

I just realized this would be useful information and is part of the problem. I perform validation on a text field on the `onBlur` event. So whenever the user exits the text field validation is performed and if it's invalid input then this dialog box will appear. So what I think is happening after this dialog box pops up it returns focus to the text box and then focus returns back to the dialog box which creates this infinite loop.

**EDIT 1**

That's exactly it, but it's because I have code that is returning focus to the text field to outline the text field as red. These are user requirements and I can't change them.

This function is called to lookup information and validate the field. If an error is returned from the JSP page then

```
function someFuncNameLookup(params){
....
//SubmitForm =  ValidateNumericInputBox('#'+ arrParams[0] +' #'+orgType+'^5^0');
// SUBMIT FORM
//if (SubmitForm.length == 0){
if (0 == 0){
 $('#Div_LoadingOverlay').show();
 $.post("/someDirectory/someFileName.jsp", 
   { ID20140411: "LookUp_org|"+ $("#"+orgType).val() + '|' + orgType }, 
    function(ID20140411_LoadDefault_data) { 
       var splitData = ID20140411_LoadDefault_data.split("%");
       var splitString = splitData[1].toString();
       var pairs = splitString.split(",");                                                      if(ID20140411_LoadDefault_data.search('orgLookupError') != -1){
     DialogBox('Div_ErrorMessage^Open^orgLookupError');
     }else{
       displayLookupData(pairs,lookupType);
     }
 });  
}else{
   DialogBox('Div_ErrorMessage^Open^orgLookupError');
}
$('#Div_LoadingOverlay').hide();
}
```

The `ValidateNumericInputBox` will return focus to text field that had an error. This is part of a library of code from another group in my company that I am "required" to use. I change the `if(0==0)` to confirm `ValidateNumericInputBox` was the reason for my issue . When I have `if(0==0)` I don't get the infinite loop. What's weird is this only happens in IE.

Comment: How are you triggering the dialog to display? What versions of the jquery libraries are you using?

Comment: so... problem solved?

Comment: @Jasen jquery-1.9.1.js & jquery-ui-1.10.3

Comment: @pennstatephil Nope. I will have to talk to the other dev group about this. I'm surprised they haven't encountered this problem. I will post a solution once I find it out.

Comment: @jasen added section for how I trigger the dialog box.